# Intellij Idea - complete next parameter shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Example:
Author author = new Author("Jack", "Daniels");
In Exlipce when filled "Jack" and pressed "enter" - it automatically went to second parameter and let me fill second one. In Intellij I always have to click with mouse, or use arrow keys.
Is there a shortcut in Intellij to make it quicker? I can't find one myself.

Comment: Did you try `Tab`?

Comment: how about comma?

Comment: None of this works. When You have String - then coma, will be just another symbol of this String. You have to close quotes, then make coma, then open another quote...It's very long. Tab just make paragraph - it doesn't go to second parameter, but makes useless space. It'll be very handy to have something which will understand that I finished my String, int or any other parameter, and I want to fill in the second one.

Comment: @MaciejFrączek I just tried on Eclipse, and what you described did not happen for me. If I enter **"Jack"** and then press enter nothing happens except that the cursor goes to the next line. And that seems reasonable since Eclipse can't know at that point whether I have completed specifying the first parameter or not. The next character I enter could be **+** (continue specifying the first parameter) or **,** (move on to the second parameter). Both are valid possibilities.

Comment: You're right...I don't know what I had in my mind...I thought it worked in Eclipse...Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since IntelliJ 2018.2

> You can now jump outside the closing bracket or quote with Tab.

(from: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/07/intellij-idea-2018-2-macbook-touch-bar-java-11-breakpoint-intentions-spring-boot-version-control-and-more/)

Basically it means if you have:

`Author author = new Author("Jack<cursor>");`

And you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the cursor is placed like this:

`Author author = new Author("Jack"<cursor>);`

Note: it doesn't matter where the cursor is initially, as long as you are somewhere inside the quotes when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> the cursor is moved outside and placed behind it. If you want to enter the next parameter you have to manually type the comma and String.

The option can be found under: `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys` and is called `Jump outside closing bracket/quote with Tab`

There are some other useful options there as well like `insert pair quote` and `insert pair brackets`.

If you want to go more advanced you can have a look into [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html).